# Modelling a Crankshaft

Tags: graphics3d, finite-element-method

In the linked documentation, a crankshaft is imported as a GraphicsComplex, which can then be turned into a Finite Element Mesh for the purposes of Finite Element Analysis. I wondered if anyone knew how one would go about creating one of these GraphicsComplexes. Is the Crankshaft modelled in some sort of CAD software first?

https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/pdes-and-finite-elements/structural-mechanics-in-3d.html

Comment: I appear to have answered my own question. I created a geometry in SketchUp, and then imported it into Mathematica as a Graphics3D (i.e. Import["file.stl", "Graphics3D"]. Then did command 'ToElementMesh. Other methods would be appreciated too!

Comment: Yes, the crankshaft was modeled in a CAD software (not sure which one) and then an STL was exported which could then be imported in Mathematica.

Comment: The [ElementMesh Generation Turorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) has a few examples how to generate meshes for FEM.